# Sending SQLite file to server iOS

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to press a button from within my application that will send a copy of the sqlite file on the device to my webservice for further operations to take place there. I keep getting no results as in it is not sending the file

here is my current code to send the file

```
- (void)sendFile
{
//NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
// NSString *documentsDir = [docPaths objectAtIndex:0];
// NSString *filePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];

NSString *fileName = @"database.sqlite";
NSString *directoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSString *serverURL = @"http://webserver/upload.php";
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
if (!fileData) {
    NSLog(@"Error: file error");
    return;
}

if (self.urlConnection) {
    [self.urlConnection cancel];
    self.urlConnection = nil;
}

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serverURL]];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"780808070779786865757";

/* Header */
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

/* Body */
NSMutableData *postData = [NSMutableData data];
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"database.sqlite\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:fileData];
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

self.urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 {
if (self.receivedData) {
    self.receivedData = nil;
}
self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
[self.receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSLog(@"finish requesting: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
self.urlConnection = nil;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"requesting error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
self.urlConnection = nil;
}
```

my current php script is

```
<?php
// In PHP versions earlier than 4.1.0, $HTTP_POST_FILES should be used instead
// of $_FILES.

$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

?>
```

My output from that is

```
 <pre>Possible file upload attack!
 Here is some more debugging info:Array
 (
 [file] => Array
    (
        [name] => onehealth.sqlite
        [type] => application/octet-stream
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpeg93fL
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 262144
    )

 )
```

More information, I am running this from a Simulator, would that be a problem? Also this leaves a copy of the sqlite file on the ipad? Or do I have to make a copy and then send the copy?

Comment: I can appease you, the multipart message seems to be OK (this is usually pretty error prone) ;)  Now, check all errors, response status code, response MIME type and insert assertions in code in order to gather more info.

Comment: Hey! I will edit my question with error info so its neater

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the Objective C code or in the PHP code.

In simple words, you are creating a form with the field '**file**' for the file to upload. So in the code php you must use the key '*file*' **instead of 'userfile**'.

The solution for PHP code is:

```
<?php
// In PHP versions earlier than 4.1.0, $HTTP_POST_FILES should be used instead
// of $_FILES.

$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

?>
```

Or if you don't want to change the php code, you can change the ObjC code, change the next line:

```
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"database.sqlite\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

for this:

```
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"database.sqlite\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

I have another suggestion:
You can use the library [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for manage request to server. You have many things resolved in it. Like upload a file.

Comment: Sorry for my english.